# Passing in array of strings into function + dynamic allocation of this array not working

Tags: c, arrays

I'm new to c programming and wanted to write a helper function for myself that should do the following

- Receiving a char** as first input parameter
- Receiving const char* as second input parameter (path to file)
- Reading in the file and populating char** with the read in lines
- Returning the number of lines read in so that the calling function "knows" the size of the passed in array

The idea is to have a helper function that will do the job of reading in a file without needing to rewrite the logic all the time again.

I continuously received segmentation faults and therefore reduced this for debugging to the following test case (still not working):

Test function:

```
int test_read_in_file() {
    char **arrayLinesOfFile;
    int numberOfRowsReadIn = read_in_file("test_file.txt",     
    arrayLinesOfFile);
    printf("%s\n", arrayLinesOfFile[0]); // gives segmentation fault
}
```

The function (reduced to a simple test for now):

```
int read_in_file(const char* pathToFile, char** linesOfFile) {
    int numberOfRows = 5;
    linesOfFile = (char**) malloc(numberOfRows * sizeof(char*));
    linesOfFile[0] = malloc(10 * sizeof(char)); // just for testing
    strcpy(linesOfFile[0], "Andreas"); // just for testing
    printf("%s\n",linesOfFile[0]); // this works fine, output "Andreas"
    return numberOfRows;
}
```

When running this test case, the printf statement in the function works fine, the printf in the test runner gives a segmentation fault.

I don't understand why this is happening. In my understanding linesOfFile would be passed by references, then I allocate memory for the first element and then sufficient elements to hold "Andreas" in the first element.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Andreas

Comment: Thanks a lot, super helpful and now working perfectly fine!

Comment: `int test_read_in_file()` misses a `return` statement.

Comment: "*In my understanding linesOfFile would be passed by references*" this understaing is wrong. There is no pass by reference in C.

Comment: Also there is no need to cast the result of `malloc()` & friends in C, nor is it recommended in any way.

Comment: And `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition.

Answer (score 2):

C uses pass-by-value. You need to pass the address of `arrayLinesOfFile` so that allocated memory is reflected in the calling function.

In other words, when you pass `arrayLinesOfFile` to `read_in_file`, a local pointer to a pointer to a `char` is made named `linesOfFile` in `read_in_file` and it points to the location where `arrayLinesOfFile` points to. When you use

```
linesOfFile = (char**) malloc(numberOfRows * sizeof(char*));
```

`linesOfFile` is made to point to the start of the allocated memory segment. **This doesn't have any effect on `arrayLinesOfFile` in the other function**. So, `arrayLinesOfFile` remains uninitialized. This explains the seg-faults.

---

So change

```
int numberOfRowsReadIn = read_in_file("test_file.txt",     
arrayLinesOfFile);
```

to

```
int numberOfRowsReadIn = read_in_file("test_file.txt",     
&arrayLinesOfFile);
```

and the `read_in_file` function to:

```
int read_in_file(const char* pathToFile, char*** linesOfFile) {
    int numberOfRows = 5;
    *linesOfFile = malloc(numberOfRows * sizeof(char*));
    (*linesOfFile)[0] = malloc(10 * sizeof(char)); // just for testing
    strcpy((*linesOfFile)[0], "Andreas"); // just for testing
    printf("%s\n",(*linesOfFile)[0]); // this works fine, output "Andreas"
    return numberOfRows;
}
```

Other changes I made in the code are

- [Removing the cast from `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)
- Add parenthesis here `(*linesOfFile)[0]` because of operator precedence.